# mod_rewrite & /+Result:+chosen+nickname+%22preorrinkap%22

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We've got Wordpress installed on our site and we're getting a lot of 404 pages coming up with the below at the end of them.

```
/+Result:+chosen+nickname+%22preorrinkap%22
```

The nickname at the end differs in almost all pages, but the url that preceeds the link is valid. By adding this at the end of a valid URL it makes the page come up as a 404.

As I understand it, there is a Wordpress exploit which bots (more than likely, due to the number of requests we are getting) are trying to use. 
(see here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26598/strange-request-uri-with-lot-of-spaces-and-chosen-nickname) What I want to do is write a mod_rewrite rule to include in our .htaccess file to detect the end text and redirect the bot to the correct URL.

For example here are a couple of our links that are coming up:

```
/News/2010/press-releases/launch-of-ondemand-video-subscription-service/+Result:+chosen+nickname+%22preorrinkap%22
/News/2010/press-releases/launch-of-ondemand-video-subscription-service/+Result:+chosen+nickname+%22coughiscout%22
```

Due to the structure of our site the links will always start with /News/ if that helps.

I've tried all manner of ways of getting the regex to pickup this pattern, but i just cant get it to work.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone comes across this you can set up the following redirect rule in your htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\+Result:\+chosen\+nickname\+(.*)$ /News/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This should redirect the bot to the actual article. It turns out I wasn't escaping the plus signs correctly in my previous attempts.

Comment: No problem, glad it was useful :)